# Mutation of class objects inside method - anti pattern?

Tags: java

Here is some example code first:

```
public class MyClass {
  List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

  public MyClass(MyObject something) {
     getStuff(something ,list)
  }

  private void getStuff(MyObject obj, List<MyObject> list) {
    //do something here and mutate the list
    list.add(MyObject);
  }
}
```

This private method was frowned upon because it mutates the list but I couldn't understand why exactly? I know other ways of doing this but I just wanted to know why this is bad/wrong.

Comment: A method called `get...` that actually does nothing but mutate; doesn't sound great ;)

Comment: If the method is private it's not *that* big of a deal, but you should still name it more appropriately.

Comment: Cause has no sense pass a member as parameter , as you can use `this.list.add` , scope of your method is only your class

Comment: *"...was frowned upon..."* By whom? Why? If they didn't say, why not **ask** them? I mean, it's not like anything would have any way to know you mutated the list, as it's in the constructor and the list is instance-specific. (Don't get me wrong, both arshajii and nachokk have very good points.)

Comment: ...as does Bill below...

Answer (score 7):

One thing I see wrong with this is that it violates the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).  You have a method named `getStuff` that returns void instead of returning... *something*.   It also changes the internal state of your class, which is surprising behavior.  I'd expect a method named `getStuff` to maybe return that list instead.

Also, this line:

```
list.add(MyObject);
```

should be:

```
list.add(obj);
```

if anything.  You need to add the instance, not the class.

Comment: "Principle of least astonishment" fails the POLS, because I'm used to it being called the "Principle of least ***surprise***" ;-)

Comment: *"...It also changes the internal state of your class..."* Well, it **might**, if you pass in the class's `list` (as in the constructor quoted). If you pass in *another* list...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh right, I didn't even notice that part.  That's... even weirder.